# Upgrading to rails 4.2.1 causes validate_uniqueness_of specs to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have an application that's currently running on rails 4.1.4, and I'm trying to get it up to 4.2.1

I'm running into problems with some of model specs when it comes to the validates_uniqueness_of declarations

My models:

```
class PromoCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :expiration_date, :code, :discount
  validates_uniqueness_of :code
end

class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

My specs:

```
RSpec.describe PromoCode, type: :model do
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:expiration_date) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:code) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:discount) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:code) }
end

RSpec.describe Coupon, type: :model do
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:code) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:code) }
end
```

The specs for presence are passing fine, but for both models, the specs for uniqueness are failing, and returning:

```
Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:code) }
  NoMethodError:
    undefined method `primary' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x007f99176e0f20>
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
it { is_expected.to validate_uniqueness_of(:code) }
```

is provided from the shoulda matchers gem. Looks like a bug. Updating that gem to 2.80+ stable should fix it. There's some details here

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/639

Comment: Ah this was it. I was on 2.6.1. Updating to 2.8.0 fixed the problem. Thanks!